# How can I correct spelling mistakes in a text document (it works for single words)

Tags: python, string, spell-checking, autocorrect

I have this code. It can be used only for words. I need something similar for a string or a text document.

```
import re
from collections import Counter
def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
WORDS = Counter(words(open('big.txt').read()))
def P(word, N=sum(WORDS.values())): 
    "Probability of `word`."
    return WORDS[word] / N

def correction(word): 
    "Most probable spelling correction for word."
    return max(candidates(word), key=P)

def candidates(word): 
    "Generate possible spelling corrections for word."
    return (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or [word])

def known(words): 
    "The subset of `words` that appear in the dictionary of WORDS."
    return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS)

def edits1(word):
    "All edits that are one edit away from `word`."
    letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R]
    transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1]
    replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]
    inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def edits2(word): 
    "All edits that are two edits away from `word`."
    return (e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through all words of your text using this code, and you're done!

```
text = "This is an exmple"
result = ""
for word in text.split():
    result += correction(word) + " "
print(result)
```

Only thing you need to do, is to fill `'big.txt'` text file with a word dictionary.

Comment: this code can be used only for simple statements. can you help me with code which can be more precise, considering UPPERCASE and punctuation

Comment: text.split() is not correct actually, you have to check for punctuation signs in the end of the word... If you need uppercase, iterate through characters of the word, store isupper() values in an array (so you'll know which characters were uppercase), process word.lower() (which is an uppercase version of your word), and then restore the case.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenizing a text is a well-studied task. Simply splitting words by space character doesn't always work as expected. You can use libraries like https://github.com/cbaziotis/ekphrasis and https://github.com/mammothb/symspellpy.